# Passing arguments from a file to a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, parameter

I've got four files:

```
./
./myscript.sh
./arguments.txt
./test.sh
```

Inside `myscript.sh`, I have to run the file `test.sh`, passing to it the arguments contained inside `arguments.txt`.

`myscript.sh` is:

```bash
arguments=$(cat arguments.txt)
source test.sh $arguments
```

This works well *if `arguments.txt` contains at most one* argument:

```
firstargument
```

The substitution is:

```shellsession
++ source test.sh 'firstargument'
```

But the problem is with two or more arguments. It does this:

```shellsession
++ source test.sh 'firstargument secondargument'
```

Also, I don't know in advance the number of arguments inside `arguments.txt`. There can be zero or more.

Comment: What you are describing is not the default behavior of bash. Are you truly using bash, or some other shell (such as zsh, which will do this)?

Comment: @Patrick Hi, it is real bash. Btw i've already got the answer thanks anyway!

Comment: Are you actually writing `source test.sh "$arguments"` with quotes? That would be one explanation for your description

Comment: I tried both with and without double quotes. With the bash's substitution i always get the singlequote. So `source test.sh "$arguments"` and `source test.sh $arguments` both result in `source test.sh 'firstargument secondargument'`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming each line of `arguments.txt` represents a separate argument, with bash 4 you can read `arguments.txt` into an array using `mapfile` (each line from the file goes in as an array element, in sequence) and then pass the array to the command

```
mapfile -t <arguments.txt
source test.sh "${MAPFILE[@]}"
```

The advantage is that splitting on spaces embedded inside lines is avoided

With lower versions of bash

```
IFS=$'\n' read -ra arr -d '' <arguments.txt
source test.sh "${arr[@]}"
```

Comment: Inside the file arguments.txt the arguments are separeted by space. Btw i tried something very similar using array and a for but didn't worked and don't know why. Well, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using a function with a `while`/`do` loop to iterate through the argument file.

Just create a file containing the function and then call the `test.sh` file within the function to iterate through the arguments contained in the `arguments.txt` file.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# Calling script

function_name ()
  {
    while read line;
    do
      . ~/path_to/test.sh $line
      do_something_commands # print to screen or file or do nothing
    done < ~/path_to_/argument_file.txt
  }

function_name # Call the function
do_something_commands # print to screen or file or do nothing
```

Comment: This is the easiest method, not sure why it isn't the top answer. I didn't even make a function. I just did `while read line; do xyz;
 done` and then ran the script with `bash myscript < arguments.txt` and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `awk`. For example:

```
arguments=`awk '{a = $1 " " a} END {print a}' arguments.txt`
```

---

Edit after reading your comment:

```
arguments=`awk '{i = 0; while(i<=NF){i++; a = a " "$i}} END {print a}'
```