# Pass a list of directories stored in a file to find command

Tags: find, tcsh

From a directory and its subdirectories, one finds all the .c files by

```
find /user/home/me/tests/ -name \*\.c
```

Now, a list of directories are stored in a file 'list_of_dir'

```
/user/home/me/test1
/user/home/me/test2
/user/home/me/test3
...
```

How can one feed them to the find command to find all the .c files in them and their subdirectories?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: the default shell for me is tcsh.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing arguments from a file to a bash script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145749/passing-arguments-from-a-file-to-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 4):

If you have a newline-separated list of directories in file `list_of_dir` and you want to pass that list to `find` safely, without *word splitting* or *pathname expansion* and without exceeding line length limits, use `xargs` (here assuming the GNU implementation for its `-d` and `-r` options):

```
xargs -r -d'\n' -I{} find {} -name '*.c' <list_of_dir
```

To be truly safe, one should use a NUL-separated list of directories, not a newline-separated list.  If `list_of_dir0` contains a NUL-separated list of directories, then use:

```
xargs -r -0 -I{} find {} -name '*.c' <list_of_dir0
```

#### How it works

- `-r` tells xargs not to run `find` unless the directory list is non-empty.
- `-0` tells xargs to expect a NUL-separated list on input.  This is the safer alternative to `-d'\n'` which tells xargs to expect a newline-separated list.
- -`I{}` tells xargs to put the directories in the find command where it sees the `{}` characters (one at a time, one `find` invocation will be run for each directory).

Comment: Thanks a lot - detailed explanation. With bash, the first one works fine for me; while the second one gives 'filename too long' after outputting a long list of files - the list of directories is pretty long in my case. However, both will not work with tcsh, which is the default at my work place.

Comment: (1) _"the second one gives 'filename too long'"_ That likely means that the `list_of_dir` file was __not__ NUL-separated.  (2) What OS are you on?
  The use of `tcsh` sometimes indicates Sun/Solaris which tends to have buggy tools.

Comment: You're right. The file was NOT NUL-separated. The first worked, so I didn't pay much attention on the output of the second.

Comment: @jianz Very good.  Since we are not using any fancy shell features, my suspicion is that the problems you see are not with `tcsh` but with aged versions of the tools `xargs` & `find` on your OS.  If you are on Sun/Solaris, you can install GNU tools and that will save a world of troubles now and in the future.  They might even be already installed: look in directories like `/usr/xpg4/bin` or `/usr/xpg6/bin`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the following up. There are no other versions of xargs or find in subdirectories of /usr. Fortunately, I can use 'bash -c' to get around the problem - inspired by 
Hauke Laging's answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ (echo /tmp; echo /var/tmp) > file
$ find $(cat file) -prune
/tmp
/var/tmp
$
```

However! This may not be so grand an idea if there are, say, newlines in the directory names, or if the list of filenames is too long for the `execve(2)` maximum on arguments...with `tcsh` you must use backticks which the bourne shells these days disfavor over the `$(...)` form

```
% find `cat file` -prune
/tmp
/var/tmp
%
```

though this again has all the same problems as suffered under the bourne shells.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works in bash. What about tcsh?

Comment: Not just newlines would cause problems but spaces and tabs, too.

Comment: Also glob (pathname expansion) characters: `*`, `?` and `[`.

Answer (score 1):

In `tcsh`, when you quote a command substitution, it is split on a *one per non empty line* basis, which sounds like exactly what you want here, so you can do:

```
find -- "`cat list.txt`" -name '*.c'
```

In POSIX-like shells, you'd need to do something like:

```
(set -o noglob; IFS='
'; find -- $(cat list.txt) -name '*.c')
```

to achieve the same.

That assumes `list.txt` contains at least one non-empty line (otherwise, depending on the `find` implementation, you'll get an error message or it will look in the current directory).

That also assumes that none of the lines start with `-` or are `find` predicates (most of `find` predicates start with `-` (`-ok`, `-print`, `-type`...), but there's also `!`, `(`, `)`...).

That also assumes `list.txt` is small enough to fit in the maximum size of arguments to a command.

Another alternative is to use `xargs`.

```
<list.txt sed 's/"/"\\""/g;s/.*/"&"/'|xargs tcsh -c 'find $argv:q -name "*.c"'
```

Where `sed` quotes each line in a format understood by `xargs`.

Same limitations as above except that it should work around the limitation on number of arguments by running as many `find` commands as needed to avoid it, and it assumes the content of `list.txt` is valid text in the current locale. Some `xargs` implementations also have a rather low limit on the maximum size of any argument which can be significantly smaller than the maximum size of a path.

Comment: Your knowledge of even obscure shells constantly impresses me!

Answer (score 0):

```
xargs -d \\n bash -c 'echo find "$@" -name \*.c' bash <input_file
```

Remove the `echo` after checking that it does what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot... This does not work for me for unknown reasons - probably my very old xargs/find as pointed out by @John1024. However, from you answer, I could use `bash -c 'find \`cat intput_file\` -name \*\.c |xargs grep main'` to get what I want now. Thanks again.

Comment: @jianz, that's not about old/new, it's about what implementation is used. The -d options is not standard and is GNU-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is with this code:

```
(echo directory1 ; echo directory2 ; echo directory3) > file
for d in $(cat file); do find $d -name '*.c'; done
```

That will put the directory names into a file run the find using the names of the directories and output the results. The apostrophes will take care of any spaces or reserved characters in the file names.